# Is there an HID protocol library that runs in Android?

Tags: android, mobile, bluetooth, hid

I want to develop an application that uses the HID protocol and sends data via bluetooth and I want to know if there is a library with useful functions for me?

I tried to check in all kinds of places but I couldn't find too much

Comment: Can you edit your post to clarify how you want to use HID.